# Unable to save history from inside a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm writing a simple bash script but the commands within the script do not anything. However it works when I copy/paste the commands directly to the command line.

```
#!/bin/bash
today=$(date +%B-%A-%d-%Y)
expr='clear|ls|cd'
history | grep -v -E $expr > histor$today.txt
history -c
```

Suggestions?

Another question: is possible to call and execute any command of the command line?

NOTE: I would like to make a script that saves my command history except the commands "clear, ls, cd" and then use crontab to save it periodically.

Comment: Hi Noah. Can you clarify what you are asking or the problem is?

Comment: The script does nothing, what do you want the script to do? What does it mean "it works" directly from the command line?

Comment: `history` is not active in scripts you need to run it using `builtin history` in scripts

Comment: @KamilCuk The script looks like it's supposed to write selected lines from shell history to a file like `historDecember-Thursday-19-2019.txt`. Why do you think it does nothing?

Comment: Though there's no point in defining the variable `expr`, if you do, you should quote the parameter expansion: `grep -v -E "$expr"` or `grep -v -E "clear|ls|cd"`.

Comment: @curusarn `history` works fine; there's just no history for it to report. `builtin history` would just run the built-in command in place of any other function or executable named `history` that might be found (i.e., `builtin` disables function and path lookup).

Comment: NOTE: I would like to make a script that saves my command history except the commands "clear, ls, cd" and then use crontab to save it periodically

Comment: Please be sure that your question has a title that's narrow enough to describe the specific problem. The number of possible scripts that "do nothing" is effectively endless. A title that says that you're trying to save the calling shell's history is much more specific.

Comment: @Noah, you can't use crontab to save your shell history periodically, because a shell started by cron doesn't have any access to the history of the other, interactive shells that the history is generated in. History that isn't flushed to disk lives in the memory of the specific shell that you're running the commands in; other shells don't have any access to it.

Comment: @Noah, ...the closest thing you could do (that uses cron) would be to set up a signal handler in your `.bashrc` that saves history whenever it gets a specific signal, and then have cron periodically send that signal to all interactive shells running under your account. But honestly, the better answers don't involve using `cron` *at all*, but instead just involve better configuration of the various knobs the shell has for configuring how and when history is flushed to disk.

Comment: You might find the answers to [preserve bash history in multiple windows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows) (on our sister site [unix.se], which is where questions about interactive shell configuration -- rather than software development -- properly belong) informative.

Comment: ok i got it, thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the history facility is only enabled in interactive shells, not shells running scripts. You can put

```
set -o history
```

at the beginning of your script to enable history.

Also, each shell invocation has its own history, it's not shared between shells. So enabling history in the script will not give it access to the history of your interactive shell. So the only history that your script would find are the commands that were executed in the script after `set -o history`.

What you should do instead is define a function in your `.bashrc`.

```
gethist() {
    history | grep -v -E 'clear|ls|cd' > $(date +'histor%B-%A-%d-%Y.txt')
}
```